# How gl.drawElements "find" the corresponding vertices array buffer?

Tags: javascript, drawing, webgl

and thanks you in advance.

I am quite new in Webgl and I don't really understand the link between the drawElements method and the current vertices buffer I want to draw. 
I understand approximatively what is happening for the drawArray method (e.g creating a buffer, binding it to the context, filling it with data, pointing to the corresponding attribute, drawing it). But when I try to do the same with a indices array and less vertices data, I encounter this type of error :

```
[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x7fae2b940800]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: bound to target 0x8893 : no buffer
```

Maybe a hint of my code could help you.

```
    const cube = new Program(renderer.gl, vertex3d, fragment); // my webgl program
    const cubeData = new Cube(); // Only array of vertices/indices
    const cubeVertexPosition = new ArrayBuffer(renderer.gl, cubeData.vertices, 'STATIC_DRAW'); // ARRAY_BUFFER
    const cubeVertexIndices = new IndexBuffer(renderer.gl, renderer.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeData.indices, 'STATIC_DRAW'); // ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER
cubeVertexPosition.attribute('aPosition', 3, 'FLOAT', false); // define attribute corresponding in vertex shader
    cubeVertexPosition.attributePointer(cube); // enableVertexAttribArray + vertexAttribPointer
    [...]
    cubeVertexIndices.draw('TRIANGLES', 0, 36); // drawElements with gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT type
```

I am successful at drawing it with drawArray :)

(the [...] is only matrices transformation for the uniforms);

Maybe you have a rapid tips in mind that could help me understand this black magic,

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawArray` use only one or several `ARRAY_BUFFER` from where vertices are drawn in order they are in the buffers, from the `first` parameter for `count` parameter.

`drawElements` use one or several `ARRAY_BUFFER` **AND** an `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` which contain indices that points to `ARRAY_BUFFER` vertices to draw. In `drawElements` the `count` parameter specify the count of indices to be read in the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, while `offset` specify an offset in bytes where to begin to read the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` (usualy `FirstIndex*sizeof(type)` where `type` can be `UNSIGNED_BYTE` (1 bytes), `UNSIGNED_SHORT` (2 bytes) or `UNSIGNED_INT` (4 bytes).

`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`:

```
[0][1][2][1][2][0][1][2][3][3][1][2][3][4][5][...
```

`ARRAY_BUFFER`:

```
|   0   |   1    |    2   |    3   |    4   | ...
[x][y][z][x][y][z][x][y][z][x][y][z][x][y][z][...
```

To properly work, the `offset` + `count*sizeof(type)` should not be greater than the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` size in byte. Also, elements index in the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` should be less than the count of vertices contained in the `ARRAY_BUFFER`.

Like `drawArray`, the `drawElements` takes currently bound buffer(s) (with attributes pointers configured) as data source. The difference with `drawElements` is that you must specify an additionnal elements (indices) buffer, using the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` target, like that :

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, myVerticesA);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, myIndicesA);
// configure attributes pointers here
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 12345, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

The "how" `drawElements` will take attributes in the `ARRAY_BUFFER` buffer(s) according indices stored in `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` depend on how you configured your attributes pointers.

Assume the following vertex buffer with interleaved positions, normals and texture coordinates:

```
|    p0    ||    n0    ||  t0  ||    p1    ||    n1    ||  t1  |
[px][py][pz][nx][ny][nz][tu][tv][px][py][pz][nx][ny][nz][tu][tv][...
```

We define the attribute pointers as the following:

```
let stride = 8*4;  // 8*float (8 * 4 bytes)
let offp = 0;   // positions at beginning
let offn = 3*4; // normals after 3*float position.
let offt = 6*4; // tex coords after 3*float position + 3*float normal 
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, offp);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, offn);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(2, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, offt);
```

Using elements (indices) buffer, GL will simply shift pointers position according indices stored in the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` buffer:

```
 // pseudo-code
 for(let i = start_elem; i < start_elem+count_elem; i++) {

   let index = ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER[i];

   attrib[0] = ARRAY_BUFFER[(index*stride)+offp];
   attrib[1] = ARRAY_BUFFER[(index*stride)+offn];
   attrib[2] = ARRAY_BUFFER[(index*stride)+offt];

 }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your rapid reply. It is a little bit more explicit for me. Your schema of the two array explain the how things are linked, but the link is not explicitly clear. There is a way to specify which ARRAY_BUFFER is "linked" to the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER?

Comment: The "link" depend on which buffers are bound when you call `drawElements`. You call `bindBuffer` with `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` as `target`, then you have the elements (indices) buffer bound, you call `bindBuffer` with `ARRAY_BUFFER` you have attributes (vertices) buffer bound. This is as simple as that. I edit my answer to specify this part.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is not WebGL. You are using some library which is clear from the code. Things like `Program`, `IndexBuffer`, `ArrayBuffer` are all part of some library you're using. How that library does things is up to that library.

In general WebGL has shaders, a vertex shader who's job it is to set `gl_Position` to a clip space coordinate for each vertex and a fragment shader who's job it is to set `gl_FragColor` to a color for each pixel.

The vertex shader usually gets data about positions from attributes. Attributes usually get their data from buffers. You tell an attribute which buffer to get data from by first binding the buffer to the `ARRAY_BUFFER` bind point with `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, someBuffer)` and then calling `gl.vertexAttribPointer` which tells WebGL how you want to get data out of that buffer (what type the data is, how many values there are per vertex, how many bytes to skip between vertices, how far in the buffer to start). `gl.vertexAttribPointer` saves all of that info for the given attribute and a reference to the current buffer that was bound to the `ARRAY_BUFFER` bind point so you are free to bind a different buffer there to setup another attribute.

When you call `gl.drawArrays` the data will be pulled from the buffers as you specified into the attributes for the shader, one set of values for each iteration of the shader

As for `gl.drawElements` it takes one more buffer, bound to `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` and when you cll `gl.drawElements` you tell it the type of data in that buffer (`gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` or `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT`). It then uses the values of that buffer to pull values out of the attribute buffer.

`gl.drawElements` is exactly the same as `gl.drawArrays` if you put a simple increasing value in the the buffer. Example

```
 const offset  = 0;
 const numVerts = 100;

 // process 100 vertices from the buffers pointed to by the attributes
 // in order 0 to 99
 gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, offset, numVerts)
```

Is effectively the same as

```
 // fill a buffer with numbers 0 to 99 (0 to numVerts)
 const numVerts = 100;
 const indexData = new Uint16Array(numVerts);
 for (let i = 0; i < numVerts; ++i) {
   indexData[i] = i;
 }
 const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

 // process 100 vertices from the buffers pointed to by the attributes
 // in order 0 to 99
 const offset  = 0;
 gl.drawElements(gl.POINTS, numVerts, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, offset);
```

but of course since in this second case you supplied the indexData it doesn't have to be consecutive.

I'd suggest reading some other [webgl tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: Thanks you gman for your answer ! Sorry for the library look alike code. It simply to do the same tutorial you linked to me, without rewriting again and again. The point is that I understand the drawArray method and I successfully applied it before. Now I am focusing on the drawElements  method which I don't find the programmatical method to bind an array buffer to the indices buffer.